# @Caching @CacheEvict not working from AOP (or component)

Tags: spring, hibernate, ehcache, spring-aop

I was wandering why my ***@Caching @CacheEvict*** annotations doesn't do anything when I put it in @Aspect which also has @component annotation.
Is it relates to the fact that this is a @Compnent? or @Aspect?

what am I missing?

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class cacheAspect {




    @After("@annotation(cacheEvictAnnotation)")
    public Object clearCachePoint(UHQueryCacheEvict uhQueryCacheEvict) throws  Throwable {
        evict();
    }

    @Caching (evict = { @CacheEvict(value= "some_key", allEntries=true) })
    evict(){
    }
}
```

when the aspect is running, it will enter the method *evict* but will ignore the annotation. which means the cache will not get evicted.

*Note: the aspect will be triggered on every method in the code which has* @cacheEvictAnnotation* annotation. (which is usually in a service method)

Comment: The reason why the `@CacheEvict` is ignored because the `evict()` method is invoked in line and not via spring bean. Try moving the `evict()` to another spring bean and invoke it from `clearCachePoint`

Answer (score 0):

As commented, the issue comes from having the `evict()` method called directly from `clearCachePoint` which will prevent any aspect like behaviour to happen.

When annotations are enforced at runtime by wrapping concrete types with the required behaviour through proxying, you cannot call methods from the same type and expect to go through the proxy.